# Docker refusing to pick up arch specification on MacOS M2

Tags: linux, docker, macos, dockerfile

I'm attempting to build a docker image, and ever since moving from an AMD64 to the ARM64 architecture, it's been giving me fits. One problem is that a lot of third-party software isn't built for the 'linux-arm64-gnu' arch, so I'd hoped to fall back to 'linux-amd64' and the Rosetta setting on v4.27.2.

I don't know where this interaction is coming from, but when I try to build a NodeJS application using it, it doesn't seem to matter how hard I specify the platform, it's still looking for the ARM binaries:

The Dockerfile reads (in part):

```
FROM --platform=${BUILDPLATFORM} docker.io/node:21 as web-builder
ENV NODE_ENV=production
WORKDIR /work/web
RUN --mount=type=bind,target=/work/web/package.json,src=./web/package.json \
    --mount=type=bind,target=/work/web/package-lock.json,src=./web/package-lock.json \
    --mount=type=bind,target=/work/.git,src=./.git,readonly \
    --mount=type=cache,id=npm-web,sharing=shared,target=/root/.npm \
    npm ci --include=dev
RUN npm run build
```

The command I issued from the command line is:

```
BUILDPLATFORM="linux/amd64" DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64 --progress plain --no-cache .
```

And yet when this runs, I get:

```
#28 0.347 Error: Cannot find module 'glob-hasher-linux-arm64-gnu'
#28 0.347 Require stack:
#28 0.347 - /work/web/node_modules/glob-hasher/index.js
#28 0.347 - /work/web/node_modules/lage/dist/lage.js
```

At which point, I'm just confused as heck.  Where is it getting that "arm64" from, given how damn hard I've tried to block it out?